# Runge's Approximation Theorem problem ??

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Since $f$ is continuous on $D,$ we know by Cauchy-Goursat that $\int_{C} f(z) dz=0,$ which is of course the case when $n=0$ in both parts. We can go by writing this for $n=1,2,...$ as well. But I don't see how to get that $t-z$ term ? Does it come from the difference quotient ? How can this be extended to prove this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No!  If $f$ is just continuous, not analytic, then Cauchy-Goursat does not tell us that.

Comment: Post the problem first, then your thoughts on it.

Comment: @zhw. thank you. Done !

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see. Then I have to worded the question differently.

Comment: $\bar D$ usually means the closure of $D.$

Comment: @zhw. I know that. Did I misinterpret that ?

Comment: Why do you write $\bar D = \mathbb C \setminus D$ then?

Comment: @zhw. That was in the question. I put it as an image as it is. I didn't write the question. It's a different  interpretation I guess.

Comment: @zhw. The designation $\bar D$ means the complement of $D$ in this context.  And you're correct.  That is not as common as the closure of the open set $D$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes I know. Just commenting on its weirdness

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of approximating $1/(t-z)$ by polynomials in $t$ or in $1/t$.

EDIT: Let $K$ be the curve $C$ together with the region it encloses.  By Runge's theorem, there is a sequence of polynomials $g_k(\zeta)$ converging uniformly to $1/(\zeta-z)$ on $K$, and in particular on $C$.  If $\oint_C t^n\; f(t)\; dt = 0$ for all $n$, then $\oint_C g_k(t) f(t)\; dt = 0$, so $\int_C f(t)/(t-z)\; dt = 0$.

Conversely, if $\oint_C f(t)/(t-z)\; dt = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb C \backslash D$, expand $1/(t-z)$ in its Laurent series with respect to $z$, converging uniformly in $t \in C$ for $|z|$ sufficiently large...

Comment: You mean by writing as
$$\frac{1}{t-z}=t^{-1}+t^{-2}z+t^{-3}z^2+ . . . ? $$

Comment: No, not necessarily.  Does the name Runge ring a bell?

Comment: Oh... the Runge Approximation theorem. We didn't cover that in class. But I will see whether I'd be able to apply that. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Robert, the name Pavlov rings a bell too.   Was that way too obscure a reference?

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't think Pavlov's theorem is relevant here.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, it is not.  I was attempting humor.  ;-))

Comment: @RobertIsrael, so Runge's theorem said that an analytic function on a compact set can be approximated by a rational function. I still don't see how to go by and apply it here.

Comment: ..and if the complement of the compact set is connected, you can approximate by polynomials.  Let that compact set be $C$ together with the region it encloses.

Comment: @RobertIsrael can you please explain how to do at least part (a) ? From that I can do the other part. Thank you.